# Split up rows by count in column

Tags: r

I got rows that are laid out as follows:

[image]

I would like this data to be turned into:

[image]

I have not tried anything myself yet in R because all I can think of is iterating over the frame in a loop and my guess is that there are more effective methods in R. Would any of you know haw this can be achieved effectively?

To those requiring a working sample here is @Ronack's method to generate it:

```
df = structure(list(Date = c("23-10-2019", "24-10-2019"),
                    `30s` = c(3, 2),
                    `40s` = c(2, 1)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Please provide the (input) data by using the output of `dput`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: @user438383 it did not answer it. Ronak eventually gave a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pivot_longer` + `uncount` from `tidyr` :

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = 'measure') %>%
  uncount(value)

#  Date      measure
#  <chr>      <chr>  
#1 23-10-2019 30s    
#2 23-10-2019 30s    
#3 23-10-2019 30s    
#4 23-10-2019 40s    
#5 23-10-2019 40s    
#6 24-10-2019 30s    
#7 24-10-2019 30s    
#8 24-10-2019 40s
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("23-10-2019", "24-10-2019"), `30s` = c(3, 
2), `40s` = c(2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: As an extra to those getting an error "Error in rep(seq_nrow(data), w) : invalid 'times' argument", make sure all NA values are removed from your production data set.

Answer (score 1):

With the `data.table` package you could do:

```r
require(data.table)

setDT(df)
m = melt(df, id.vars = 'Date', variable.name = 'measure')
m[, .(Date = rep(Date, value)), .(measure)]
```

**data** (from @ronak)

```r
df = structure(list(Date = c("23-10-2019", "24-10-2019"),
                    `30s` = c(3, 2),
                    `40s` = c(2, 1)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: I haven't down-voted, though I agree it would have been good to add a sample data.frame in the first place. Anyway, you added it now.